# WP if condition showposts

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I have this code which works okay for what I wanted but I will probably need to put a condition if there's only 2 posts then wrap it in a `<div class="large-6">` then if there's 3 posts then wrap it in `large-4`.

Just a little confused how to add a condition statement.

```
<?php
                $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio',  'showposts' => '3', 'offset' => '1' ) );
            ?>
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="large-4 columns">
                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

To Pieter:

something like this? if so, that didn't work though unless I'm doing it totally wrong and noobishly.

```
<?php
                $query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => '3',
                    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                     'offset' => '1'
                ));

                while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

                   <?php if(!isset ($query->posts[2])){ ?>
                    <div class="large-6 columns">
                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                        <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                    <?php } else {?>
                     <div class="large-4 columns"> </div>
                    <?php }?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a theory but should work. Here is the idea:

`$loop->posts` holds an array with all the posts with all their resepective postdata. So, with that in mind, it should be easy to determine whether you have one, two or three posts in that array by simply checking if a certain array key exists

So you basically needs to check if you have a third post, so you can try something like this

```
if( !isset( $loop->posts[2] ) ) {
  //add div if less than 3 posts
}else{
  //add div if you have 3 posts
}
```

**EDIT**

Just a note. The OP has changed the query variable from `$loop` to `$query` in his original code. `$loop` should be changed accordingly

Comment: You have changed your query variable to `$query`, so you should change `$loop` accordingly, so my code should become `$query->posts[2]`

Comment: I changed it to query now nothing outputted. Please see my edit.

Comment: Ok, so my code seems to work. It doesn't output anything because you have nothing in your else statement, just an empty div

Comment: Oh aha I thought it would automatically determine the post count. Nvm it does work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put conditionals like

```
<?php if(condition) : ?>
    code to execute if condition == true
<?php elseif(condition2) :?> // repeat as many times as necessary
...
<?php else :?>
    final else if needed, you can just end the if statement if it's only one condition, if you have else if else this is needed
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's basically it...

Comment: Sorry but could you construct it as I'm totally confused about it.

Comment: I'm also confused. Please add a proper explanation to your code. Does this really answer the OP?

Comment: It's a general way to construct if-else statements in php. You can do with it what you want. I thought OP had sufficient knowledge how to implement it, given that he had the code above, and that he knows what the code does ;)